# Postgresql Prefix in django orm

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

How could I go about utilizing the [Postgres Prefix Plugin](https://github.com/dimitri/prefix) within django? Is there a way to just append an additional `WHERE` clause to the queries that django runs without going into raw SQL?

Maybe something like this?

```
Model.objects.filter(field1=2, field2__in=[1,2,3]).where("prefix @> '0123456789'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, this is the [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) method on `QuerySet`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
 Model.objects.filter(...).extra(where=["prefix @> '0123456789'"])
```

Comment: My concern is that it will be deprecated soon according to their docs.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no fixed deprecation plan yet so it will be there for several versions and at the time they remove it, there will maybe be another way to do that. Right now, the only other way I see to achieve your goal is to use raw sql queries (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)  but you will have to write the whole query yourself.